# what AWS EC2 instance is best suited to set up socket.io websockets that need to handle many connections and many small msgs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, socket.io

**The situation**

I have finished developing an app that uses a few websockets to enable communications. so far i have used a couple of free heroku instances but now i need to scale my project. In particular one of the websockets will need to handle a great deal of very small msgs (aprox. 50 characters or bytes) basically each of my say 30000 connections broadcasts its status (i.e. the 50 letter msg) every 3 seconds and each of these needs to be broadcast to all other open connections without excesive delays (say 1.5 seconds) my concern is that 30000 * 30000 * 50 (aprox. 40 gb every 3 sec.) is a rather large number and I lack experience regarding how well websockets scale or whether this load is high or low for an EC2.

**My thoughts and questions**

first of all can you think of the best suited EC2 instance to acheive this or at least get close to it?

I could think of a way to prioritize my msgs so that each status is only broadcast to say the 5000 (i.e. 1/6*30000) connections that care about it the most, thereby reducing the volume; but it would involve using compute power to generate this prioritization for every outgoing msg, thereby potentially cannibalizing resources the socket needs (I am speculating here). Is this a sensible approach? should I do this?

the other approach would be to simply use multiple websockets to do the same job but am not sure how many i would need nor with which characteristics. or if this aprroach actually turns out cheaper.

if you have experience with websockets and are able to help  i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

`Memory optimized instances` are best for your situation.

You can use `Network Load balancer` to handle hight traffic of WebSockets Later.

Comment: Thanks Ravindra, do yopu have exprience with setting up high traffic websockets?

Comment: we would like to simulate high traffic to see how our app copes could you point us in the right direction regarding this